# Segula for marriage: saying Shir Hashirim 40 nights in a row?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, segulah, shir-hashirim, personal-request-bakashot

When I was in yeshiva, someone told me of a segula for finding one's zivug is to say Shir Hashirim 40 nights in a row, at chatzot.

Does anyone know of any mention of this segula anywhere?

Comment: Sounds like a way to be tired on your dates...

Comment: I've looked around a bit. It seems to be parroted by everyone, but I have yet to see a source.

Comment: @ElonMusk I would be happy to hear about parroting too, feel free to share some :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii here are some links:
https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/40-days-shir-hashirim 
              https://www.imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31768#41559 
              https://outorah.org/p/51935/

You can just Google it and find a million sites saying the same thing.